# Use one machine to send mail with 2 ip's

Tags: unix, smtp, iptables, sendmail

I need to config one SMTP server (sendmail) to send mail with 2 interfaces with different ip's  depending server.

For example: In same machine with to ip: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 i need to send email a@a.com by 1.1.1.1 and b@b.com by 2.2.2.2

I don't now if i can configure it on sendmail, or use iptables, some idea ?

Thx.

Comment: What is this requirement for? Sending mail offsite won't matter from the SMTP's point of view. Perhaps, can you explain what you are ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you want something different (sorry to tell you that). But *if* you really want to send mail over different interfaces/routes you have to have these two interfaces in two different networks, which should each have a router. Look at your OS' manpage for the `route` command, the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/networks` files and possibly, how to setup your NICs. Set a static route for the non-default network. This non-default network must of course reach b.com.

Answer (score 0):

I found some help about this, but not say nothing to send mails with diferents ip's or interfaces, using virtusertable.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5033970.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on how to do this using exim at http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch30.html#SECID146. The option you're looking for is "interface"